# How to get rid of the bottom gnome-panel in gnome 3.2?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3

How to get rid of the bottom gnome-panel in Gnome 3.2?  Cant figure this out..There is no options when I right click on it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out from an ArchLinux forum. 
You have to press the 'Alt' button, then try to right click. You'll be prompted with a menu.

Comment: Thank you! That saved my head from super explosive headaches!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other panels? Since GNOME requires you to have at least one panel, add another panel, then delete the bottom one.

Comment: I have the top panel, with "Applications" "Places". 
The right click option has completely disappeared so I cant access any options.

Comment: No idea then. Sorry.